# Ansible doesn't taking "enter" as a value

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

i was working on Ansible project which is cyberpanel automation and i want to pass enter as a response to my prompt.

I tried several things including regex in the expect module but it is not working.

If anyone got up with a answer please let me know,

My section of code is as follow's

```
expect:
               command:
                       sh installer.sh
               echo: yes
               responses:
                      (.*) Please enter the number(>*): "1"
                      'Full installation \[Y/n\]:': "Y"
                      (.*) Remote MySQL(.*): "n"
                      (.*)Press Enter key to continue with latest version or Enter specific version such as:(.*): ""
```

[This is where i need to pass an "Enter"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pvg8H.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pvg8H.png): [This is what the output looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qvOF.png)

Comment: Could it be a conflicting `:` in the dict key? Try quoting them, just like with `Full installation`.

Comment: Nevermind, I tried that, at least, Python yaml parser handles that without quotes.

Comment: @bereal No it is not working do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: How about `\n` for the response?

Comment: @bereal Thank you for your time and quick response i figure it out by entering it as `(.*)Enter specific version such as:(.*): ""`. Thank you <3

Answer (score 1):

i figured out the answer by avoiding some part of the response and providing some regex into it.

The working code is

```
expect:
               command:
                       sh installer.sh
               echo: yes
               responses:
                      (.*) Please enter the number(>*): "1"
                      'Full installation \[Y/n\]:': "Y"
                      (.*) Remote MySQL(.*): "n"
                      (.*)Enter specific version such as:(.*): ""
```